# Error in the logs, in the QuickOSM panel, copy/paste it and report it to GitHub

Tags: error

I'm getting this message everytime I try to use QuickOSM:

> Error in the logs, in the QuickOSM panel, copy/paste it and report it to GitHub

Do you know how I can solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This message is telling you there's an error message somewhere else, namely the QuickOSM tab of the Log Panel.

Open the Log Messages panel (View menu... Panels... Log Messages) and find the "QuickOSM" tab. There may be lots of tabs. Here's mine:

[image]

Then you are being invited to find the actual error there and create an issue on Github with it. In my window there's only INFO messages because my query worked okay. You might see things tagged as ERROR? That's probably the relevant bit.

The relevant Github repository is: https://github.com/3liz/QuickOSM - get an account if you don't have one and use the "issues" section to submit a report with the error text from the messages tab.